# Ruby: Better way of showing year if it is not this year

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails App, I display `created_at` like `month-day`, like`03-21`.
However, when the year is not this year, this kind experession may be confusing, so I want to display `2014-03-21` when the year is not `Time.now.year`.
This is what I came up with

```
<% if tweet.created_at.year == Time.now.year %>
  <%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%m-%d") %>
<% else %>
  <%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
<% end  %>
```

But I think this code is quite a bit long, is there any other better of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 options. Both elegant, see what you'd like.

1.Using the strftime as you are.

```
<%= tweet.created_at.strftime( tweet.created_at.year == Time.now.year ? "%m-%d" : "%Y-%m-%d") %>
```

2.Using `I18n.localize`. Asuming you got 2 formats for localization (e.g. `full` and `short`).

```
<%= I18n.l(tweet.created_at, format: (tweet.created_at.year == Time.now.year ? :short : :full)) %>
```

Comment: +1 for using I18n. You have specified same format in both cases in first solution. Also it probably should be moved into a helper method.

Comment: Fixed the bad c&p thanks. And yes, it definetely should be moved out of the view into a helper or even a decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Bit shorter is using the [ternary operator](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/The-Ternary-Or-Conditional-Operator.htm):

```
<% tweet.created_at.year == Time.now.year ? tweet.created_at.strftime("%m-%d") : tweet.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the `time_ago_in_words(tweet.created_at)` helper, this shows a more intuitive and human readable timestamp.

Comment: I think this depends on the actual requirements.

Comment: Of course! I explained how I usually approach this kind of situation, but as there are plenty of answers he will choose the solution that better fit his requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this

```
<%= tweet.created_at.strftime(tweet.created_at.year == Time.now.year ? "%m-%d" : "%Y-%m-%d") %>
```